# How to add an environment variable with letters and numbers combined in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to setup my stack and while I am using this:

```
version: '3.4'
 services:
  .
  .
  .
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD: MyPassword001
      - ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:services.db.environment contains {"SA_PASSWORD": "MyPassword001"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string

Is it possible to use such value for an environment variable in docker?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in single or double quotes `- SA_PASSWORD: "MyPassword001"` or `- SA_PASSWORD: 'MyPassword001'`

Comment: Yes, no difference @mchawre

Comment: Try env-file option https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option

Comment: env-file option seems to be working lt me see if it can connect to the db

Comment: Let me put it in answer section. So everyone can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make use of [env-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) option in docker compose.

```
version: '3.4'
 services:
  .
  .
  .
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    env_file:
      - my.env
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
```

`my.env` file contents:

```
SA_PASSWORD=MyPassword001
ACCEPT_EULA=Y
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).

Answer (score 3):

The [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) section has two possible syntaxes:

```
version: '3'
services:
  list_of_assignments:
    environment:
      - KEY1=value1
      - KEY2=value2
  dictionary:
    environment:
      KEY1: value1
      KEY2: value2
```

You're trying to combine the two syntaxes and that isn't allowed, which leads to the validation error you're getting.  Either remove the `-` at the front of each line to use the dictionary syntax, or change each line to *e.g.* `ACCEPT_EULA=Y` with an equals sign and no space.

Comment: I have to test it out, eitherway thanks for your answer